# Selecting maximun value in postgresql table when maximum values are not distinct

Tags: postgresql

I have a table coltures_report with fields application_id, coltures_id and row_step. I would like to get the maximum value for row_step grouped by a combination of application_id and coltures_id. However row_step can have not unique values and I would to get all the rows with the maximum values.

```
id  | application_id| coltures_id | row_step |
----+---------------+-------------+----------+
  1 |     1169      |      4      |    5     |
  2 |     1169      |      5      |    5     |
  3 |     1169      |      2      |    0     |
  4 |     1124      |      1      |    5     |
  5 |     1124      |      1      |    4     |
  6 |     1156      |      1      |    5     |
  7 |     1156      |      2      |    5     |
  8 |     1156      |      3      |    5     |
```

Expected result is

```
id  | application_id| coltures_id | row_step |
----+---------------+-------------+----------+
  1 |     1169      |      4      |    5     |
  2 |     1169      |      5      |    5     |
  3 |     1124      |      1      |    5     |
  4 |     1156      |      1      |    5     |
  5 |     1156      |      2      |    5     |
  6 |     1156      |      3      |    5     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select cr.* from coltures_report cr
where not exists (
  select 1 from coltures_report
  where application_id = cr.application_id and row_step > cr.row_step
)
```

or with `rank()` window function:

```
select cr.id, cr.application_id, cr.coltures_id, cr.row_step
from (
 select *, 
   rank() over (partition by application_id order by row_step desc) rn 
  from coltures_report
) cr
where cr.rn = 1
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
select cr.* from coltures_report cr
where cr.row_step = (select max(row_step) from coltures_report where application_id = cr.application_id)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=657665355f0f02ba5d2dacc70c5f7d2d).
Results:

```
> id | application_id | coltures_id | row_step
> -: | -------------: | ----------: | -------:
>  1 |           1169 |           4 |        5
>  2 |           1169 |           5 |        5
>  4 |           1124 |           1 |        5
>  6 |           1156 |           1 |        5
>  7 |           1156 |           2 |        5
>  8 |           1156 |           3 |        5
```

Comment: both queries dont'work since I would to selecto only rows with the maximum value of row_step. In the example above, your approach returns also nto maximum values for row_step within the application_id group

Comment: The confusing part of your question is: *...grouped by a combination of application_id and coltures_id* so initially my queries returned maximum of each combination of application_id and coltures_id.